# The volume of a classic paraboloid at $h$

Tags: integration, volume, plane-geometry

So, I have an object

$z=x^2+y^2$

filled with water at $h=50$ where $h=0$ is at the deepest spot of the paraboloid. With this information I am to find out the volume of the water in the object.

Now, I can determine the lowest point fine enough (or just cheat and notice that since it's a classic paraboloid the lowest point is at $(0,0,0)$), but will knowing $h$ of the paraboloid make it simple for me to determine the $r$ of it?

I was thinking I could $somehow$ observe the $x$~$y=c$ at point $(0,0,h)$ with $x^2+y^2=50$ (classic circle with $r=5\sqrt2$?)

and then conclude that $V_{paraboloid}=\frac{\pi hr}{2}=answer?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

The paraboloid as the $z$ axis as axis of symmetry, so you can find the volume as the [solid of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution) of the parabola $z=x^2$ around the axis $z$, for the values $0<x<\sqrt{h}$.

Your observation that $r=\sqrt{h}$ at the height $h$ is correct, but the volume is $V=\frac{\pi}{2}r^2h=\frac{\pi }{2}h^2$

Comment: I see. How unmathematical is it to simply notice that there is no reason to assume that the deepest point of the parabola wouldn't be at the point (0,0)?

Comment: Given the symmetry  we can flip the vertex of the parabola from $(0,0,0)$ to $(0,0h)$without problems, but changing the limits of integration.